# Navigation using Managed Metadata (Term Store) OR Add metadata navigation on custom page layouts

Tags: 2013, administration, configuration, architecture, information-management

I am working on a SharePoint 2013, where i created a new Enterprise wiki site collection. the requirement we get from our customer is as follow:-

1. we need to add 6 metadata columns for the wiki page, so when users create wiki pages they need to fill in the 6 columns as follow:-

[image]

2. then users should be able to filter the wiki pages using term store. for example if they click on certain term , it should filter the wiki pages that have the term inside it.

so i find mainly two approaches to accomplish this :-

1. using Tree view as described in this  [Link](https://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/)
2. OR using Managed navigation [Link](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/07/20/sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata-term-store-aspx/)

seems both are intended to satisfy my requirements, but both offers totally different approach to follow, so can anyone adivce on which one is preferred (if any), and what are the general differences between these 2 approaches ?